# select list of date between date range with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

hi i have a goals want to generate list of date between 2 date but i also have some condition like this :

Table_A : Maximum Delivery Time and Week off

```
Code      Max_delivery_time      Week_off
 01               4                  6
```

Note :
Maximum_delivery_time it contains the number of day that we can deliver an item
week_off it contains the day in every week that deliver can't be process values 1-7
1 = monday, 2 = tuesday etc

Table_B : Table Day off

```
Code       Date_day_off 
 01         2021-26-05
 02         2021-28-05
```

Table B contains date day off that must be exclude if the day is on range

so i would like to select list of the date inside the date range with condition :
date start must be +1 day from today
date finish is (sysdate+1) + "Max_delivery_time". But if the day inside is contains a day in Week_off and date from table b date_day_off it will change to next day sample :
Today is : monday, 2021-05-24

the result will be

```
List_of_day
2021-05-25
2021-05-27
2021-05-30
2021-05-31
```

is it possible to generate it with a query ?

Comment: what is the type of Date_day_off?  is it really year day month?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) your sample output just has the four dates for your sample Table_A record, but uses all the dates from Table_B, even the one with a different Code; does Code in Table_A not have anything to do with Code in Table_B?  2) what does the output look like if there are multiple rows in Table_A?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: `Table_A` - does it contains 1 row only? *1 = monday, 2 = tuesday etc* Why so strange? Why not like for WEEKDAY() function (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday). `Table_B` - incorrect date literals. *the result will be* Why '2021-05-31' is skipped?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Akina sorry i skip 31, i should be contains 31 i have edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use recursive cte :

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        CURRENT_DATE() List_of_day 
        , Max_delivery_time 
        , Week_off
        , 0  as counter 
        , DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAYno
        , 1 as flag 
    from Table_A ta 
    union all 
    select ADDDATE(List_of_day, 1 ) List_of_day 
        , Max_delivery_time + case when DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(List_of_day, 1 )) -1 = Week_off then 1 when b.code is not null then 1  else 0 end  Max_delivery_time 
        , Week_off
        , counter +1 counter
        , DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(List_of_day, 1 )) - 1 DAYno
        , case when DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(List_of_day, 1 )) - 1 = Week_off then 1 when b.code is not null then 1  else 0 end as flag 
    from cte 
    left join Table_B b on  ADDDATE(List_of_day, 1 ) = b.Date_day_off
    where counter +1 <= Max_delivery_time
)
select List_of_day from cte
where flag = 0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a81579a5867794daf6fe57e60113e44)*

Comment: this is work in my sql 8.0 and it's correct what i means. but could i use recursive in mysql under 8.0 ? i think it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Deaaa mysql as of February 1, 2021 mysql 5.6 is not even supported anymore , I recommend upgrade it to latest version [MySQL Product Support EOL Announcements](https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html)